# Clarify if a browser also caches resources gotten with anchor href, dynamically-generated-html and javascript fetch?cache

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I know that the browser can cache files using the src in an image or script tag in HTML. So we need to update the resource name or hash it so the browser will be forced to download it again so it can update locally.

e.g.

```
<img src="cat.jpg">
<script src="my-script"></script>

<!-- update names so browser can download these sources instead of using what's in cache -->
<img src="cat.jpg-updated">
<script src="my-script-updated"></script>
```

Although I'm still unclear with the specifics and was wondering if anyone can clarify a few points for me.

- Do browsers also cache the HTML documents in the anchor tags (I think yes, but just want this to also be clarified)
- Will they also add resources to cache if the HTML tags are **dynamically generated** on the page with frameworks like Angular?
- Will browsers also try to add resources to cache if it interprets them in javascript code such as fetch?

I'm trying to get these points clarified so that I can know whether I should also be worried about hashing the paths provided in my programming code. Thanks

### Update clarification for first point:

I'm still new to browser cache so I don't know if the static document html page also gets caught by the browser (I feel like it does as some browsers have offline mode, although here I don't know how browsers would handle re-downloding the resource since I believe you don't need to keep updating the url each time)

e.g.

```
<a href="http://some-static-website.com/page">Go to static Page</a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your first point?

Comment: Do you actually mean *cache*, and not *catch*?

Comment: @MattWay yes I meant cache ^^

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir added an update to the question in response to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. If you ask the browser to request a URL, by typing in the address bar, clicking a link, `src`, `fetch`, whatever, it will try to find a cached version. It also depends on how the server is set up, but most servers have some basic caching enabled, and if your server is caching some things, you can probably assume the behaviour is the same for everything.

For dynamically generated HTML the browser won’t cache the generated HTML but it will cache the script that generates it.

Comment: Thanks for this, btw just want to finally clarify 2 more points after if that is ok..
- Since dynamically loaded html won’t  go in cache I’m also guessing dynamically loaded scripts will also not go in cache too right?
- Also if browsers cache everything, what should I do to get a browser to reload a static html document that needs to be updated without changing the url? (e.g. www.my-static-site.com/page)